# Separate Unicode and Ascii Charactors with White Space from PHP

Tags: php

I'm Doing some class to Handle Sinhala Unicode from php, I want to separate mixed string Unicode  and ascii char as a separate words with white space. 
example:

---

```
$inputstr = "ලංකාABCDE TEST1දිස්ත්‍රික් වාණිජ්‍යTEMP මණ්ඩලය @ MNOPQ"; 

function separatestring($inputstr)
{
//do some code 
return $inputstr;
}


echo separatestring($inputstr);

//OUTPUT String = ලංකා ABCDE TEST1 දිස්ත්‍රික් වාණිජ්‍ය TEMP මණ්ඩලය @ MNOPQ
```

i have try with preg_replace with Regex and several looping methods but any method did not success. please help me on this. Thanks All!

Comment: If you have tried, show us the code. We can start to help from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$inputstr = "ලංකාABCDE TEST1දිස්ත්‍රික් වාණිජ්‍යTEMP මණ්ඩලය @ MNOPQ"; 

function separatestring($inputstr)
{
    $re = '#\s+|(?<=[^\x20-\x7f])(?=[\x20-\x7f])'
          . '|(?<=[\x20-\x7f])(?=[^\x20-\x7f])#';
    $array = preg_split($re, $inputstr);
    return array_filter($array); 
}


echo implode(" ", separatestring($inputstr));
//OUTPUT String = ලංකා ABCDE TEST1 දිස්ත්‍රික් වාණිජ්‍ය TEMP මණ්ඩලය @ MNOPQ
```

The regexp for splitting means the following:

- `#` — start regexp (delimeter character),
- `\s+` — split on one or more whitespace character (counting the whitespace as the separator),
- `|` — or,
- `(?<=[^\x20-\x7f])(?=[\x20-\x7f])` — split on a border between non-ASCII and ASCII characters (not counting them as separators),
- `|` — or,
- `(?<=[\x20-\x7f])(?=[^\x20-\x7f])` — split on a border between ASCII and non-ASCII characters (not counting them as separators),
- `#` — end regexp (delimeter character).

Unfortunately, my regular expression is not too elegant, so sometimes the empty strings are returned (because whitespace is also an ASCII character). I’ve put `array_filter` to fix this, but a more elegant solution might exist.

I’ve written `separatestring` in such a way that it returns in array. If you want a string, replace the `return` statement this way:

```
return implode(" ", array_filter($array));
```