# Separate Unicode and ASCII charactors with whitespace

Tags: regex, c++builder

I'm developing a C++ class in C++Builder for a Sinhala Unicode translator.  I want to split a mixed Unicode and ASCII string by adding whitespace.  PHP and C# regex expressions do not work in C++Builder.  My last PHP request was successfully answered ([Separate Unicode and Ascii Charactors with White Space from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599687/separate-unicode-and-ascii-charactors-with-white-space-from-php/42599933#42599933)).  I need help to overcome this matter in C++Builder.

This is my C# code, and this code works fine:

```cs
string pattern = @"\s+|(?<=[^\x20-\x7f])(?=[\x20-\x7f])|(?<=[\x20-\x7f])(?=[^\x20-\x7f])";

string[] substrings = Regex.Split("ලංකාABCDE TEST1දිස්ත්‍රික් වාණිජ්‍යTEMP මණ්ඩලය @ MNOPQ", pattern);

string text = string.Join(" ", substrings);

//text out put = ලංකා ABCDE TEST1 දිස්ත්‍රික් වාණිජ්‍ය TEMP මණ්ඩලය @ MNOPQ
```

This is my C++Builder code so far, which does not work:

```cpp
const UnicodeString pattern = "#\s+|(?<=[^\x20-\x7f])(?=[\x20-\x7f])|(?<=[\x20-\x7f])(?=[^\x20-\x7f])#";
UnicodeString  text = L"ලංකාABCDE TEST1දිස්ත්‍රික් වාණිජ්‍යTEMP මණ්ඩලය @ MNOPQ";

//String str;

TStringDynArray substring = TRegEx::Split(text, pattern);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Your C++ `pattern` does not match your C# `pattern`.

In C#, the [`@` verbatim prefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) allows you to write string literals without having to explicitly escape reserved characters, like `\`.

In your C++ code, you are not escaping any of the `\` characters, so many of them are being treated as [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) instead of actual `\` characters.  You need to escape actual `\` characters as `\\` in string literals, eg:

```
const UnicodeString pattern = L"\\s+|(?<=[^\\x20-\\x7f])(?=[\\x20-\\x7f])|(?<=[\\x20-\\x7f])(?=[^\\x20-\\x7f])";
```

Alternatively, if you are using one of C++Builder's [C++11 enabled compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers), you can use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) instead.  Which it appears you *attempted* to do by surrounding the string content with `#` delimiters, however you forgot the required `R` prefix and parenthesis attached to the delimiters, eg:

```
const UnicodeString pattern = LR"#(\s+|(?<=[^\x20-\x7f])(?=[\x20-\x7f])|(?<=[\x20-\x7f])(?=[^\x20-\x7f]))#";
```

That being said, note that C++Builder's [`TRegEx`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx) internally uses the open-source [PCRE library](https://www.regular-expressions.info/pcre.html), so check its documentation for supported regex expression syntax.

Comment: Thanks for answer, when i try 1st with \\ regex is work but not to my needs, i want split unicode and ascii with single white space, 2nd line is return with error, with "R", c# regex syntax is not match for c++ is it.

Comment: As I said, the `R` prefix requires a C++11 compiler. You did not say which of C++Builder's several compilers you are actually using.  Not all of them support C++11 (specifically, the "classic" Win32 compiler, and the OSX compiler).  Also note that `TRegEx` has had problems with Unicode handling in the past, and probably still does.  So you should consider finding a 3rd party RegEx library for C++

Comment: Thanks for your Help Remy, I have done it with your guidance, now it work as i expected.